# Basic multilingual lualatex document

Tags: fonts, luatex, arabic, multilingual

Traying to write a multilingual document with english as main lang, french and arabic. What is the basic preamble? I tried to start with this but it doesn't helped me.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[bidi=basic,arabic,french,english]{babel}
\babelfont[arabic]{rm}{Amiri}
\usepackage{microtype}
\begin{document}
foo
\end{document}
```

Comment: remove the \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}. But apart from this: "it doesn't helped me" is not a sensible problem description.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thank you for your replay. I get errors about unvalid utf8 and using TeX--XeT. i am runing lualtex

Comment: @UlrikeFischer `\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[bidi=basic]{babel}
\babelprovide[import=en,main]{english}
\babelprovide[import=fr]{french}
\babelprovide[import=ar]{arabic}
\babelfont[arabic]{rm}{Amiri}
\babelfont[english,french]{rm}{Arial}
\usepackage{microtype}` with this it run without error is it OK?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Perhaps there would be benefit to modifying either `fontenc` or `fontspec` so that the incompatible `[T1]` is detected, and throw an error message? I believe I have seen a similar issue more than once here at SE, when the user writes bad encoding requests, simply because it is seen in the numerous older questions and examples.

Comment: @rallg T1 (or T2A or LGR or ...) is normally a bad idea in lualatex, but it is not incompatible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you need. For small chunks of texts in the secondary languages (words, sentences, maybe groups of a few paragraphs), there is no need to pass the languages as options:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[bidi=basic,english]{babel}

\babelfont[arabic]{rm}{FreeSerif}

\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}

One \foreignlanguage{arabic}{اثنان ثلاثة أربعة} five
\foreignlanguage{french}{six sept}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

For more complex documents, you can use:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[bidi=basic,french,english]{babel}
\babelprovide[import]{arabic}

\babelfont[arabic]{rm}{FreeSerif}

\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}

One \foreignlanguage{arabic}{اثنان ثلاثة أربعة} five
\foreignlanguage{french}{six sept}.

\end{document}
```